# Is there a way to convert EXPRESS data modeling language into .NET Classes?

Tags: .net, express

Does anyone know if there are any tools out there that are able to convert data models in the [EXPRESS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPRESS_%28data_modeling_language%29) data modeling language into .NET Classes and types?